# function that returns `True` if a string contains exactly two instance of a substring and `False` if it doesn't

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, count

I'm trying to write a function that returns `True` if a string contains exactly two instance of a substring and `False` if it doesn't.

I'm getting an error:

```
return' outside function
```

I feel I'm very close but just can't quite get it, I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction.
Should recursion be used?

```
s =  ("xeroxes")
exes = str(x)
count = 0
def has_two_X(s):
    count = s.count(exes)
    for exes in s:
        count = +1
       if count ==2:
        return True
       else:
        return False
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("string has :",count.s(exes))
```

Comment: You didn't keep the contents of the function indented, so your `return` isn't in the function (that's what your error message is telling you). Indent all the code that's supposed to be in the function. Also, I'm assuming your first line is supposed to have quotes around `xeroxes`.  Side-note: `if boolcondition: return True else: return False` can be simplified to `return boolcondition`. And your loop is redundant with the count call. So in this case, the entire function can collapse to `return s.count(exes) == 2`.

Comment: Your indentation looks odd; all the code in the function needs to be indented...

Comment: You're right I edited the code and tried again but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code must return True if there is two or more instances of substring, you can create a dictionary and return True if value is there in dictionary or not.

```
mydict = {}
for letter in s:
    if letter in mydict:
         return True
    else:
         mydict[letter] = 0
return False #Since there is no substring (two substring can be formed only if it has two same letters in the string)
```

To find exactly if it has two substring, I would recommend the same approach where you can maintain the dictionary and the count of substring present. Add all the substring/count to the dictionary, this would take O(n^2) to generate all substrings and approx- O(n^2) hashmap memory.

After constructing hashmap, you can iterate over the hashmap to return True if it has exactly two occurences of substring.